# How to make it possible to work on multiple screens in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

As in the title question - is it possible to ensure data synchronization beetween separate cards / screens in Angular application?

Any example would be greatly advised.

Comment: That would be fundamentally against the idea of a one page application. And most of the time, I would go so far as to call this a web app anti pattern. However, as Angular gives you 2 way data binding, you can easily make that a three way data binding, if you persist the stuff you need to sync in your database. Some cloud based dbs like Firebase will even give you this out of the box. I still would not recommend that.

Comment: You can save stuff to localStorage and read it from another browser window as long as you're on the same domain. Not sure if you connect a watcher to localStorage tho, so you would have to create some kind of long polling mechanism.

Alternatively, you could set up a websocket solution that runs things from the server.